# Get specific value out of the Terraform state file

Tags: terraform

I've deployed my infra using Terraform and I noticed that I have some interesting information in the state (`terraform.tfstate`) file of terraform which I would like to extract. For example

```
$ terraform state show 'packet_device.worker'
id                = 6015bg2b-b8c4-4925-aad2-f0671d5d3b13
billing_cycle     = hourly
created           = 2015-12-17T00:06:56Z
facility          = ewr1
...
```

which I would like to transform somehow to

```
$ terraform state show 'packet_device.worker.id'
6015bg2b-b8c4-4925-aad2-f0671d5d3b13
```

But adding the `id` at the end doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions how I can achieve this behaviour?

Comment: In case other folks find it useful, it's worth noting that the `state show` command has changed its output format from the version described in this question to something more JSON-like (but not quite) as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/67461595/2053165 - the solution in both cases is the same if you need to extract a specific value: switch to `terraform show -json` and pipe to `jq`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Terraform **state show command** is used to retrieve all the attributes of a given resource and you won't be able to fetch a single attribute from it as the argument is resource **ADDRESS** and is used to refer a resource specifically. Documented in https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/resource-addressing.html

What you can do is store the resource attribute in output value and use the command

**terraform output {output-valaue-extractor}**

Refer: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html

Answer (score 13):

You can utilize `terraform show -json` and `jq` to get a specific value out of a Terraform state file.

```
terraform show -json <state_file> | jq '.values.root_module.resources[] | select(.address=="<terraform_resource_name>") | .values.<property_name>'
```

You have a state file named `terraform.tfstate` and a Terraform resource as `packet_device.worker` and you want to get `id`. Then it would be as follows:

```
terraform show -json terraform.tfstate | jq '.values.root_module.resources[] | select(.address=="packet_device.worker") | .values.id'
```

`terraform.tfstate` also can be omitted since it is the default name for the state file.

Answer (score 3):

The primary way to export information from a Terraform configuration is to declare [Output Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html) in your root module. You can then access them using [`terraform output`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/output.html) once the apply has completed. If you need that information in a machine-readable way, you can alternatively run [`terraform output -json`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/output.html#json) from the consuming program and parse the output as JSON.

If you are in an unusual situation where you need programmatic access to *all* values in the state (for example, if you were implementing some sort of generic Terraform state visualization tool) then you can instead use `terraform show -json`, which will print out all of the data from the state in [a JSON format](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/json-format.html#state-representation).

If you *are* accessing only specific values, perhaps to integrate with some other system in an automation solution, I'd recommend using explicit Output Values because then it's explicit to future maintainers what the interface with the caller is, and so they are less likely to accidentally break the caller by e.g. refactoring the `packet_device.worker` resource into a child module, which would cause it to appear in a different place in the state. The usual assumption is that the resources inside a module are an implementation detail of that module and thus that you can safely refactor them as needed as long as the output values remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the exact value and are willing to install `jq`, the other answers here are great!

If you're looking for a quick answer to manually copy/paste, etc., piping to grep does the trick.

ex:
`terraform state show 'packet_device.worker' | grep "id"`

which would show the relevant line(s), like:

```
id = 6015bg2b-b8c4-4925-aad2-f0671d5d3b13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `linux OS` just use grep. I did it like this:

`terraform state show aws_instance.myFirstInstance[0] | grep 'public_ip'`

That was to get only the value after I did everything.
The recommended way in my perspective is to use output or get it to json.