# how to extract data from terrafrom state show

Tags: terraform

I would like to extract the data given from `terraform state show`. According to documentation we should use `terraform show -json` . https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/show.html

> The output of terraform state show is intended for human consumption,
> not programmatic consumption. To extract state data for use in other
> software, use terraform show -json and decode the result using the
> documented structure.

Not sure how to use `terrafrom state show` in conjuction with `terrafrom show`

```
$ terraform state show 'packet_device.worker'
# packet_device.worker:
resource "packet_device" "worker" {
    billing_cycle = "hourly"
    created       = "2015-12-17T00:06:56Z"
    facility      = "ewr1"
    hostname      = "prod-xyz01"
    id            = "6015bg2b-b8c4-4925-aad2-f0671d5d3b13"
    locked        = false
}
```

Comment: `terraform state show` does not have `-json` option. So not sure what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Marcin I have updated above question. Please let me know it helps.

Comment: You just use `terraform show -json`, not `terraform state show`. Have you tried that?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to get the state of one resource? What do you want to do with the resulting `json`?

Answer (score 12):

The `terraform state show` command displays information on a single Terraform resource and does not support the `-json` flag. The command `terraform show` dumps the entire state, and does support the `-json` flag. Unlike the output from `terraform state show`, the output of `terraform show -json` is [documented](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/json-format.html) and intended for programmatic consumption.

If you want to obtain the info on a particular resource as displayed by `terraform state show`, you can extract it from the full-state JSON, for example by using `jq`:

```
terraform show -json | \
jq '.values.root_module.resources[] | select(.address == "packet_device.worker") | .values'
```

Whether this makes sense depends on what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.