# Access terraform backend s3 variables

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following code:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "my-sandbox-terraform-state"
    key            = "dev/iac/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    profile        = "sandbox"
    dynamodb_table = "sandbox-dev-terraform-locks"
    encrypt        = "true"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use the value "my-sandbox-terraform-state" from the variable bucket like:

```
locals {
my_bucket = terraform.s3.bucket
}
```

Is there a way to access the values defined in the terraform backend block as read variables?

Comment: Why would you need those?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811596/get-specific-value-out-of-the-terraform-state-file

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: The reason is because I want to use the same bucket (different sub-folder) to store other files.
I create the backend file dynamically, so to "solve" it I just added a locals block in the end.

Answer (score 0):

A backend block cannot refer to named values (like input variables, locals, or data source attributes). You can use a partial config & then pass them in using the `-backend-config` CLI argument:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/configuration#partial-configuration